# How do I select items where the date is today in SQL, when the date it is reading is in a converted datetimeoffset format?

Tags: sql, ssms, zapier

Trying to select items from a database where the date that is being entered is converted to a different timezone.
In this case, the date is entered into the server in UTC time, and I've got a select query offsetting this date to meet the NZST time zone:
[Code attempted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLSwe.png)

I'm also trying to select the items where the date in this 'NZSTdate' column match with today's date, and have had no such luck casting both items in the date format in a WHERE clause.
Just says the conversion failed from a character string.

```
SELECT *, convert(datetime, switchoffset(fulldate, datepart(tzoffset, fulldate AT TIME ZONE 'New Zealand Standard Time'))) AS 'NZSTdate'
  FROM [Analytics].[dbo].[Call logs] 
  where cast('NZSTdate' as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
  order by 'fulldate' desc
```

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few things going on here.

- "cast('NZSTdate') as date" looks suspicious.  You almost certainly don't want the apostrophes around the field name like that.
- Similarly, you don't want "fulldate" in apostrophes either.

Does this get you closer to what you're attempting?

```
create table #kl (dt datetimeoffset )

insert #kl values (getdate()) 
-- changing timezone
select switchoffset(dt, '-04:00') 
from #kl
-- getting rid of time time component of dt and getdate()
where convert(date, dt) = convert(date, getdate() )
```